# Sending Adobe agreements on custom object relationship error

Tags: lightning, custom-object, relationships, button

I have created a custom send for signature button for a specific Adobe Agreement in Salesforce lightning using the following:

{!URLFOR('/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess', null, [masterId = myCustomObject__c.Id, templateId='a2aJA0000000eVBYAY'])}

However, when trying to generate the agreement from myCustomObject, I get the error:

Didn't understand relationship 'myCustomObject__c' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL...

I have read through a past post that is very similar but did not see an actual resolution.
Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: try removing the spaces around the equals sign

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Change myCustomObject__c to myCustomObject__r.Id.

When you're pulling fields like that you have to use __r instead of __c if you're referencing an object from a different object.